# D-Link DIR-635 can be used as a "receiver"?

Tags: router

We have a huge antenna at the top of our main office roof. We also have another antenna in our apartment to "receive" the signals. Can the D-Link DIR-635 do this? After a few hours of going thru the Web Interface, we could not find a setting to do this.

Is there a way to set this router as a "receiver"? What is this option generally called? So that we will know what to look for.

THanks,
Wenbert

Comment: option can be called "client mode". It will use the wireless connection as its wan link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a "bridge" connection between the two access points. According to this spec sheet: http://bc.whirlpool.net.au/bc/hardware/?action=h_view&model_id=520 it sounds like that model is not able to be set to this mode.  This is not an official list though.

Note: A bridge connection would require the access points to be dedicated to the bridged connection and not be used as general access points for other users to connect to.